# AdS/CFT phenomenology and realistic FRW model building

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle, de-sitter-spacetime

Are there any examples of realistic holography (likely as a de Sitter type Universe: as it approximates FRW / is an FRW solution without baryonic and dark matter). I don’t see why one wouldn’t be motivated to say the current regime of cosmology is approximated by de Sitter space and therefore a dS/CFT model is a fruitful area of study?

If there are any examples of holography in applied / realistic cosmology, I would appreciate them being linked or listed!

I’ve personally found that the most interesting and robust examples of AdS/CFT are for speculative / toy models so I wondered if there are realistic constructions. I appreciate any input!

Comment: dS/CFT used to be a "fruitful" area of study, only to be damped by the recent "swampland" conjecture.

Comment: @MadMax dS/CFT was always interesting, but was it so fruitful? There were only a handful of examples...

Comment: There is some work done that I know of related to cosmology and there is probably even more. I am not really following these papers, but you might want to have a look at Skenderis's work. For example https://inspirehep.net/record/1729271, and https://inspirehep.net/record/1476594, https://inspirehep.net/record/1275612